# i was developing this android apk and suddenly got errors

Tags: android, react-native, cross-platform

**i was trying to implement functionality and got errors for android and it works good in ios development multiple dependencies installed for push notification and all**

*is it any problem with reactnative version 0.70
do i need to upgrade the version of reactnative*

```
18 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

  1.  Dependency 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-31.

      Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
      plugin 7.3.0 is 33.

      Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
      plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
      compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).
termines which devices the app can be installed
      on).
```

https://github.com/manan36chauhan/Notification_react_native/issues/1

i have tried to resolve errors for changing build.gradle and version downgrading and upgrading still not having any solution

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this? [image]

I have an app with     "react-native": "0.70.6", and it works without errors.

It'll be better if you share more code.

Comment: i tried to add more code but rejected by stackoverflow i am sharing link for all errors
https://github.com/manan36chauhan/Notification_react_native/issues/1

Comment: Hi Mana, so you've got this problem after installation of the Notification_react_native? 

If this is the problem, why you don't try this package? 
https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/installation

Comment: currently i am using this package for foreground notification and badges count  "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.0",